# Setting Init VC in App Delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, appdelegate

I am trying to init my core data stack with the init VC of my app. To do this I want to pass the core data manager i have created into the first VC upon loading.

I thought this code would make sense to pass the coredatamanager into the VC, however I get errors whichever way i write this code, im sure im missing something simple?

```
        // Initialize Storyboard
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "RoutineController", bundle: Bundle.main)

    // Instantiate Initial View Controller
    if let viewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? ViewController {
        // Configure View Controller
        viewController.coreDataManager = coreDataManager

        // Set Root View Controller
        window?.rootViewController = viewController
    }
```

Error is simply:

> Use of undeclared type 'ViewController'

However if i delete 'as? ViewController' I get an error on the following line that viewController has no property coreDataManager.

Is there some sort of delegate i need to define in the viewdidload of the view controller in sending to?

**EDIT** Revised my code to correct the storyboard ID, however the code inside the {} doesnt seem to execute, i get the printed error i wrote due to the if let failing, so this still isnt the right way to set the viewController...any ideas as to why?

```
        // Initialize Storyboard
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

    // Instantiate Initial View Controller
    if let viewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? RoutineController {

        // Configure View Controller
        print("SENDING THIS INFO TO THE FIRST VC \(self.coreDataManager)")
        viewController.coreDataManager = self.coreDataManager
        // Set Root View Controller
        window?.rootViewController = viewController
    } else {
        print("WE COULDNT SET VIEWCONTROLLER AS THE DESIGNATED VC SO MOC WASNT PASSED")
    }
```

Comment: You sure your storyboard file is called RoutineController.storyboard?

Comment: no the VC is called RoutineController, the storyboard is main, updated the OP with one that seems to work now if anyone can verify this is accurate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that you need to define an identifier in the if let viewController to find it successfully, the working code is as follows:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as? TabBarController {
        viewController.coreDataManager = self.coreDataManager
        window?.rootViewController = viewController
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
as? ViewController
```

should be

```
as! UIViewController
```

alternatively this should also work:

```
as! RoutineController
```

Comment: I thought this but then it throws "Downcast from 'UIViewController?' to 'UIViewController' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?"

Comment: yeah i think casting it directly as the controller name may be the solution, ill do further testing

Comment: Great! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Select the RoutineController in your storyboard and set the storyboard ID

[image]

Then use the Storyboard ID here:

```
    if let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "<storyboardID>") as? RoutineController {
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to make sense and doesnt fire an error, but the code inside the {} after the as? Routine Controller isnt running, updated the OP and the print command isnt running at all